# MySQL query case statement in where optimization

Tags: mysql

I am writing a query in mysql i am not familer with the recursive query to much.
how and what i need to do to optimization of the below query as the conditions i put not looks good ,there must be a easier way to do same.

```
 select
   b.entity_id 
from
   entity_hierarchies a,
   entity_hierarchies b 
where
   a.entity_id = 25 
   and a.entity_type = 'user' 
   and b.entity_type = 'idea' 
   and a.Geography_Geography = 
   case
      when
         a.Geography_Geography is null 
      then
         a.Geography_Geography 
      else
         b.Geography_Geography 
   end
   and COALESCE(a.Geography_Country, '') = 
   case
      when
         a.Geography_Country is null 
      then
         COALESCE(a.Geography_Country, '') 
      else
         b.Geography_Country 
   end
   and COALESCE(a.Geography_DistrictOrCounty, '') = 
   case
      when
         a.Geography_DistrictOrCounty is null 
      then
         COALESCE(a.Geography_DistrictOrCounty, '') 
      else
         b.Geography_DistrictOrCounty 
   end
   and COALESCE(a.Geography_State, '') = 
   case
      when
         a.Geography_State is null 
      then
         COALESCE(a.Geography_State, '') 
      else
         b.Geography_State 
   end
   and COALESCE(a.Geography_City, '') = 
   case
      when
         a.Geography_City is null 
      then
         COALESCE(a.Geography_City, '') 
      else
         b.Geography_City 
   end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Intro

I noticed you could rewrite some of these statements in a much simpler form.

So for example:

```
and a.Geography_Geography = 
   case
      when
         a.Geography_Geography is null 
      then
         a.Geography_Geography 
      else
         b.Geography_Geography 
   end
```

can simply become:

```
AND ( a.Geography_Geography is null or a.Geography_Geography =   b.Geography_Geography )
```

### Final Solution

```
select
   b.entity_id 
from
   entity_hierarchies a,
   entity_hierarchies b 
where
   a.entity_id = 25 
   and a.entity_type = 'user' 
   and b.entity_type = 'idea' 
AND ( a.Geography_Geography is null OR a.Geography_Geography =   b.Geography_Geography )
AND ( a.Geography_Country is null  OR  a.Geography_Geography = b.Geography_Country )
AND ( a.Geography_DistrictOrCounty is null  OR a.Geography_DistrictOrCounty =  b.Geography_DistrictOrCounty )
AND (   a.Geography_State is null  OR   a.Geography_State =   b.Geography_State )
AND ( a.Geography_City is null  OR  a.Geography_City =   b.Geography_City );
```